# Why is this powershell script not working?

Tags: powershell, device

I am trying to write a power shell script that will automatically disable particular sound devices. When I ran it for debugging everything look fine. It had asked me if I was sure I wanted to disable the device and I clicked yes But when I checked the device properties it was still enabled. Is there something I’m doing wrong, or should I do something else for my intended purpose.
This is the code I ran in Admin powershell I haven’t started the automation part yet)

```
Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName “Speakers (Yeti Nano)” | Disable-PnpDevice
```

Comment: Check out the difference for you between `Get-PnpDevice -Class MEDIA` vs `Get-PnpDevice -Class AudioEndpoint`. I found I had to disable the media device, instead of the matching AudioEndpoint

Comment: what does `Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName “Speakers (Yeti Nano)” | Disable-PnpDevice -whatif` output?

Comment: @anothervictimofthemouse It asks me if I’m sure that I want to disable the device

Comment: Append `-Confirm:$false`